# SQL Binary Microsoft Access - Combining two tables if specific field values are equal

Tags: sql, ms-access, binary

I am new to Microsoft Access and SQL but have a decent programming background and I believe this problem should be relatively simple.

I have two tables that I have imported into Access. I will give you a little context. One table is huge and contains generic, global data. The other table is still big but contains specific, regional data. There is only one common field (or column) between the two tables. Let’s call this common field CF. The other fields in both tables are different.

I’ll take you through one iteration of what I need to do. I need to take each CF value in the regional, smaller table and find the common CF value in the larger, global table. After finding the match, I need to take the whole “record” or “row” from the global data and copy it over to the corresponding record in the smaller regional table (This should involve creating the new fields).

I need to do this for all CF values in the regional, smaller table. I was recommended to use SQL and a binary search, but I am unfamiliar. Let me know if you have any questions. I appreciate the help!

Comment: You can start reading about MS Access SQL in [`Fundamental Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140011%28office.10%29.aspx). There are two further articles in the series. MS Access allows you to build queries in the query design window using wizards. You can join two tables with drag and drop of the relevant field.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the MS Access specific dialect, but in T-SQL, it would be something like:

```
Update Regional SET Regional.A = Global.A ...
FROM Global WHERE Regional.CF = Global.CF
```

And as long as CF is unique in Global, you should be there.

Comment: I will experiment with this. Because of the large amount of data, will this be efficient? Will sorting the data (CF happens to be a number value), from smallest to largest, help to make this a binary search and make it faster?

I am experimenting with how I even use this code within Access - I created a new query and am in "SQL view" for the query.

Comment: Don't work much with Access, usually use SQL server, where I try not to second guess the query optimizer as it is pretty smart.  It also depends on what you define as a large amount of data...

Comment: Why access, just out of interest?  If this is a one off thing that you are doing, you could even copy your tables to SQL express (free) for the update.

Comment: The need is Access because I need to optimize this process as these tables will be imported/updated monthly. Afterwards, macros need to be used using the "new" table data to determine the data quality.

Comment: Personally, I would move away from access if possible (it's a headache), but other than that, afraid I can't offer you much more advice.

Comment: What would you suggest as the front end in the move away from Access? I think you forget that Access is a reporting tool, a RAD and a number of other things as well as using a Jet/ACE back-end database. SQL Server takes a lot more administrative skills than does MS Access.

Comment: @Remou - this is all true, however you can use access as a front end for SQL tables as well.  I have found myself struggling with access in the past as things get more complex.